# rails 3.1: how override inherited_resources and permit rails scaffolding to work normally again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, scaffolding

SOLUTION FOUND: See comment

Building a new rails 3.1 app. Started with a basic blog_entries model to get the hang of it. No surprises.

Then I added ActiveAdmin, got that working okay with my existing model.

But now when I try to scaffold a new model/etc with this:

```
rails g scaffold Community name:string guid:string
```

everything seems right (views, migration) except the controller does not have CRUD options and looks like this:

```
class CommunitiesController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

The problem is that ActiveAdmin uses inherited_resources which prevents manual rails scaffolding from working normally.

Does anyone know a way to force rails to scaffold "correctly" despite ActiveAdmin using inherited_resources?

Comment: found a reference to the -c command line argument for 'rails generate scaffold'. To force rails to use the normal scaffold generator, add -c=scaffold_generator to the end of the command

Comment: oops: -c=scaffold_controller (not _generator)

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Using the -c part at the end has no effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946980/running-rails-generate-scaffold-does-not-generate-model

Comment: can't explain that, it worked perfectly for me: rails g scaffold ETC ETC ETC -c=scaffold_controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the following to override `inherited_resources`:

```
-c=scaffold_controller
```

Comment: Why does inherited_resources appear on some scaffolds?